# Pass a 2d array pointer to a function and allocate memory inside the function

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I have the following code, where I pass a 2d dynamic array to a function. The function has to allocate memory for the array and insert values in it.

As I am passing by pointer, I receive the pointer as a pointer to the 2d array. However, I get an error when I try to allocate memory for it.

```
void generateMatrix(int ***Matrix, int rows, int cols, int rank){

**Matrix = new int* [rows];
for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<rows; rowIndex++)
    *Matrix[rowIndex] = new int[cols];

srand(time(NULL) + rank);

for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<rows; rowIndex++)
     for(int colIndex=0; colIndex<cols; colIndex++)
        *Matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]=rand();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

int rank, procSize;
int matSize;
int **Matrix = NULL;

matSize = atoi(argv[1]);

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm globalComm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

MPI_Comm_rank(globalComm,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(globalComm, &procSize);

std::cout<<"The number of processes are"<<procSize<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"The rank of the process is "<<rank<<std::endl;

std::cout<<"The size of the matrix is "<<matSize;

//1D-row agglomeration each process is going to store a set of continguous rows
int localRows = matSize/procSize;

int *v;
gen(&v);

generateMatrix(&Matrix, localRows, matSize, rank);


MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

I get error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘int*’ in assignment on the line **Matrix = new int* [rows].

How exactly should this be done? (A 2d array pointer be passed to a function for allocating memory and setting values)

Comment: You have 3 stars in the parameter, but use only 2 stars when trying to write to it.

Comment: This is really a horrible idea all around, use a vector

Comment: `*Matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]` should be `(*Matrix)[rowIndex][colIndex]`. same with `*Matrix[rowIndex]`

Comment: Only call `srand` once.

Answer (score 2):

just do this:

```
*Matrix = new int* [rows];
```

Explain:

the triple pointer contains address of double pointer
and actully you want to create array for double.

***Matrix (in generateMatrix fun) is adress of **Matrix (from main)

(in generateMatrix fun)
*Matrix is **Matrix (from main)

Think about it if we do this in main:

```
int **Matrix;
Matrix = new int *[row];
```

so we trasport Matrix by address to another fun using &.

i hope my explain helpful.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: see the answer. add some explain